# Are any limitations exist as to using different versions of git software on the same physical repository?

Tags: git

For example when working from computers which have different git software versions installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git repository backwards compatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314668/git-repository-backwards-compatibility)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

git's repository layout has been very stable over time, so using even very old versions of the software with repositories created by later versions should work fine.  Of course, there may be config options set by later versions that aren't understood by earlier versions of the tools, but this should not cause problems except perhaps that the older software doesn't behave as you would expect.

Also, it should be fine to use versions of the tools built for different operating systems on the same on-disk repository.

There are particular features, such as submodules, that may not be supported by older versions of git - to be able to assess whether that would be a problem you would have to tell us what the oldest version you might be using is.

You might also want to look at this question about git's backwards-compatibility:

- [Git repository backwards compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314668/git-repository-backwards-compatibility)